# Unable to install the Broker

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, agent

After a Xamarin update, I no longer can connect to the mac machine using the mac agent in windows. I have done all of the troubleshoot that was provided online.

- CheckList
- I can ping both machines.
- I can ssh into my mac.
- I cleared caches.
- I even reinstalled the mac.

Still no luck.

in the log all it states is

```
Unable to install the Broker
Couldn't connect to ip address. Please try again.
An unexpected error occurred with the current SSH Session
Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: An established connection was aborted by the server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you updated Xamarin, did you only update the Visual Studio side? If so, please make sure that both Xamarin for VS and Xamarin on your mac
are both updated to the same update channel.

## Switching update channels

In Xamarin Studio, you can switch the update channel with the Xamarin Studio->Check for Updates… menu, choosing  Stable, Beta, or Alpha in the drop down next to Update Channel and then clicking the Switch Channel button.

In Visual Studio, navigate to menu Tools->Options and scroll down to expand the Xamarin section and select "Other". Choose Stable, Beta, or Alpha from the drop down menu and click Check Now. If updates to that channel are available, you will get a dialog similar to the above for Xamarin Studio. Proceed as above.

Comment: Yes, I have already done that. Both machines at stable level are up to date.

Comment: I got the both machine connected successfully through the mac agent by changing to both updates to beta. I am not sure why stable mode will not work. Thanks jgoldberger.